# HTML Rendering in Calculated Columns - SharePoint 2019 on premise

Tags: calculated-column, html, 2019, sharepoint-server

I know that for 2013 and 2016 on premise that there is the capability to adjust a web app setting to allow HTML rending in calculated columnsm via PowerShell:

CustomMarkupInCalculatedFieldDisabled

Links on this:

[Handling HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-fields-a3db28e4-747c-437e-b085-8f795b722a8c)

[SharePoint Online/2016/2013: HTML Rendering in Calculated Columns](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/40146.sharepoint-online20162013-html-rendering-in-calculated-columns.aspx)

But does anyone know if this web app setting is in SP 2019 on premise?

We will definitely check when we get a SP 2019 farm built but I wanted to see if someone has checked into this already.

Answer (score 3):

This is not available in 2019. However, column formatting is and can do most of what you want to accomplish for custom field rendering in a modern list view. You can also use SPFx Field Customizers as needed.